# What is the proper way of using client-side routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a question regarding AngularJS and Node.js.
I have a web application and I use client-side routing with routeProvider to navigate through the pages of my web application.
And I get the data through a RESTful API server-side. But all of logic is done in AngularJS, because with the client-side routing, all I do in Node.js is :

```
exports.partials = function(req, res, err) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render(name);
};
```

So, I only use Node.js to render the template layout and the partial view, but all of the logic is in AngularJS.
Is it the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Angular.js is a javascript framework to create a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) or Single page application.

It creates its own navigation system using the hash(#) or hashbang(#!) in the url to represent the different states or pages of your application but all this happens in your home page. The browser never changes to another page because all application state will be lost in a page refresh (HTTP is a stateless protocol).

Usually you need 3 parts to create an Angular application each one with it's own routing system.

1. Your angular application: All the scripts and resources are loaded in the home page. The routing system is provided by $routeProvider and the hash(#). Eg: http://mywebsite/#/products or http://mywebsite/#/providers. All this is relative to your home page.
2. Your templates: This is retrieved using ajax and can be routed however you want, Eg: http://mywebsite/product.html or http://mywebsite/templates/product.html serving static html files or even http://mywebsite/templates/products using a restful approach and a server side routing mechanism.  There is no general rule here because basically depends on the server technologies chosen and your own design.
3. Your data: Usually a Resful API to supply you application with business data stored in a database. [Rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) creates some basic rules you must follow like treat everything as a resource and manipulate it with verbs. Eg: GET http://mywebsite.com/api/products or POST http://mywebsite.com/api/providers

This is an example of an Angular route provider

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
            templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
            controller: 'ChapterController'
        });
```

In this case angular will fetch your home page from http://mywebsite.com initially and the template from the content of your chapter.html file located in http://mywebsite.com/chapter.html and your data from whatever configuration you set to your $http service. As long as you set your routes in a way that don't conflict with each other you are safe. In your case you can use express.js to create a restful routing system for your templates or serve them directly from the public folder as html.